# I have a question regarding DC machines

Tags: electrical-engineering

You can measure the back emf constant of a DC motor by driving it as a generator at a known speed and measuring its open terminal voltage. For example, if the speed of a DC motor was 1000 rpm and its terminal voltage was measured to be 10 volts its back emf constant would be 0.0955 V/rad/s.

If the motor had no load (nothing connected to its shaft) and was then connected to a variable voltage supply which was adjusted so that its speed was again 1000rpm why is the terminal voltage now higher? Also would the back emf constant of the motor change in this scenario?

Comment: There is a no load current required to produce the magnetic field in the motor and there is a resistance that it must flow through. This voltage drop helps the back EMF oppose the supply voltage, so the supply voltage must be higher.

Comment: Thanks DKNguyen